# Extract html from to a specific tag with Python

Tags: python, html, selenium

```
<div class="question_text_edit">
   <h3>This is a heading</h3>
   <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

I want to extract the pure html code in a “string” format in python in order to pass this in HTMLTOTEXT function. I need only the  childs. I’m using selenium in python.

Comment: what do you mean with pure html code? do you want to includes the tags or not? are you looking for all html elements or not?

Comment: yes i want to keep all tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming what you want, based on your example, is a string like this:

`html_string = '<h3>This is a heading</h3><p>This is a paragraph</p>'`

If you want to do this with pure selenium, try the following:

```
""" Create your webdriver as 'driver' and then begin here """

parent_el = driver.find_element_by_class_name('question_text_edit')
children = parent_el.find_elements_by_css_selector('*')

html_string = ''.join([child.get_attribute('outerHTML') for child in children])
```

Now `html_string` should contain your HTML.

### Notes:

`find_element_by_css_selector('*')` has the potential to be pretty slow, depending on the HTML you are parsing. There may be an alternate way to accomplish whatever your overall goal is, without doing it exactly this way.

Comment: I had a typo, in the first line `find_element_by_class` should have been `find_element_by_class_name`. Also `find_element_by_css_selector` should have been `find_elementS_by_css_selector`... Sorry! Typing too fast :)

Comment: I have this error 
html_string = ''.join([child.get_attribute('outerHTML') for child in children])
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable

Comment: Check my previous comment, I needed an "S" on "elementS" for `find_elements_by_css_selector` only

Comment: @CosmaIaffaldano Refresh the page and copy/paste my code. It's working for me without that error now

Answer (score 1):

Try `BeautifulSoup`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('<h3>This is a heading</h3>')
tagname=soup.h3
print(tagname.string)
```

It will return `This is a heading`

Comment: Ok this works, but i need to use with any html code, after the call of item['question'] = hxs.select('//h1/span[2]') select function of scrapy